# Return array backwards from current month

Tags: javascript

Currently it's January.

```
  var d = new Date();
  var m = d.getMonth();
```

`console.log(m)` will out put 0;

I have an array:

```
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

I want to return the last 4 months.  Starting from current month.  So in this case.
Jan, Dec, Nov, Oct.
How can I achieve this?

```
var monthSliced = months.slice(m, m4).reverse();
```

returns: `["Apr", "Mar", "Feb", "Jan"]`
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can loop four times, each time you loop, you can use `months.slice(m).shift()` to get an element from your array. Using this method of retrieval will allow you to enter negative indexes and retrieve elements from the end of your array:

```js
const d = new Date();
let m = d.getMonth();
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];

const result = [];
for(let i = 0; i < 4; (i++, m--)) {
  result.push(months.slice(m).shift());
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing it will be this:

```js
const months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
const result = [];

for(let i = currentMonth; i > currentMonth - 4; i--) {
  result.push(months[(months.length + i) % months.length]);
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth();
var months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
var result = [];


function getPreviousMonths(month, count) {
    if(count > 3) return;
    if(month === -1) month = 11;
    result.push(months[month])
    getPreviousMonths(--month, ++count)
}

getPreviousMonths(currentMonth, 0, [])
console.log(result)
```